# Loading a page browser says Waiting for another URL (not mine)

Tags: security

So when I'm waiting for CiviCRM to load in the bottom left of the browser it says Waiting for scorpioindustries.com.... (which is not my URL)

What could this be a sign of? Have tried loading in different browsers and different computers so it's not a browser or computer infection. I ran virus checkers on my site and nothing. I checked manually through the CiviCRM stack and couldn't find any reference to this URL. I ran a search in the MySQL database for "scorpio", "scorpioindustries" etc but nothing emerged from that.

Any ideas? I initially thought virus but I'm a little stumped now.... Maybe this is a Site Name sort of setting inside of CiviCRM?  Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the Net tab within [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) while loading the page.  It'll display all the page components that get loaded.  Something in your page (whether you put it there or not) is attempting to load something (an image, a script, who knows) from that domain.

Comment: The scorpioindustries.com website has a number of images of cars.  Perhaps you have used one of these images on your webpage?

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of of that url. Are you using a drupal theme which might load external stylesheets, fonts etc.. from that domain? Or a drupal module which loads external javascript from that domain? I would first rule that out before jumping to conclusion and suspecting hacking or a virus.

Answer (score -2):

Try checking your hosts file and running a anti-spyware scan. Porn websites and downloading free .mp3 music files as of my last knowledge in 2009 can cause spyware infections, such is of the signs as the following: you try to go to http://www.google.com and on typing and pressing enter you would be redirected to another website. when on one web site, your web browser skips to another site automatically.

Is your computer acting slow? Avoid using free music downloading programs such as Limewire or BearShare, and try avoid installing tool bars that might be offered upon installation of programs. First update all anti-virus, anti-spyware, anti-rootkit, anti-adware data bases and try doing scans with all of these. Install a firewall program; don't use the built-in default programs that come with Windows.

Do research and do Windows Update, but do research on the updates that you plan to install; only install manually, don't use automatic update. Download the Windows updates manually and install them manually. as Windows updates can conflict with other programs.

In safe mode, chkdsk c: / f / r /v at a command prompt, type y for yes if prompted to reboot. Upon reboot, Windows will check the disk for errors. Disk scanning for errors and scanning for malicious software one time a week is necessary. Also use the Microsoft Malicious Software Removal Tool.  Zone Alarm is a good firewall, ad blocker also, and http://www.iptools.su.

Do Google searches on every program before installing. Also look for free programs that you burn to a blank cd to scan under the operating system. Assuming you're using Windows XP platform; Win 7, Win 8 and Win 10 are all crappy and use way to much memory. Also try Glary Utilities.

Try to do a ping from a command prompt on that specific web site.

Comment: Welcome to CiviCRM.SE. I have edited your post for readability; however, even after doing so, I must downvote as although I believe you have correctly identified malware as the culprit, and you offer some reasonable advice, the post is overwrought or misleading or out of date elsewhere. For example, no consumer who cares about security in 2019 should be running Windows XP, which hasn't been supported for half a decade. Disk scanning will not save you from malware problems. Few modern notebooks include optical drives. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.